# Expected identifier or "(" when adding picker

Tags: xcode, identifier

Hello I am getting this error when i attempt to add a picker :UIViewController UIImagePickerControllerDelegate ... Any suggestions..thanks

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GPUImage.h"
#import "GPUtutorialCell.h"

@interface GPUtutorialViewController :UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>


UIViewController { //expected identifier or "("
    NSMutableArray *filterNames;



}


- (IBAction)Load:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)Save:(id)sender;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *filtersTable;


@end
```

Comment: What's the stray `UIViewController` for before your open bracket (`{`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIViewController { //expected identifier or "("
    NSMutableArray *filterNames;
}
```

It looks like you're trying to declare an instance variable. But a stray `UIViewController` has worked its way into your code. Delete it. Like this:

```
{
    NSMutableArray *filterNames;
}
```

Comment: This builds successfully when i delete UIViewController but the emulator loads a black screen and an error message in the lower right "all output" reads (lldb)

Comment: i think leeching is kind of a strong term for someone new to this site. I also had no idea that I have the ability to accept answers. Thank you.